Is Karl Popper's falsificationism self-refuting?
I am referring here not to falsification as a tool used to judge if something is good science, but rather to judge the meaning of statements such as "God exists".
Suppose that Flew's parable of the gardener shows that this statement can't be falsified, and so the statement "God exists" is meaningless.
Does this process of falsification not self-refute, and so Flew's argument fails? Is the proposition "A statement is only meaningful if it can be falsified" itself falsifiable?
If not, then surely that makes falsificationism meaningless.

"A statement is only meaningful if it can be falsified" .. is this an accurate portrayal of the idea of falsificationism? I'm not convinced

When I Google it, I get quotes more like this: "Karl Popper argued that any research that wishes to be considered scientific must subject its hypotheses to falsification; to test it, to try and prove it incorrect." - it's the criteria for determining if something is scientific, not if something is meaningful or even true

@TKoL I know that was his goal, but (unless I'm wrong) Flew used it to show that religious statements are meaningless, sort of as an alternative to verificationism

so it's a specific flavour of falsificationism this is about, specifically Flews, and not falsificationism in general, is that right?

I personally am a big fan of falsificationism as a criteria for science but not at all for meaning or truth

@TKoL I guess yeah, nothing really to do with science

I agree with the above comments: Popper's falsificationism is not a criteria of meaning.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Traditionally no, but it is used by some to discredit religious language and say that religious statements are non-cognitive

Compare with Verificationism the original Neo-positivist criterion of meaning.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not really specifically interested in questions of God's existence or meaning of religious language. I'm more wondering if falsificationism is specifically self-refuting.

You aren't describing Popper's falsificationism but something more like logical positivism or American pragmatism.

Famous guy said, "Everything is false! Everything is permitted!" (now we just need to find to permits office)

No, Popper's falsificationism is not self-refuting.
What does it mean for falsification to be self-refuting? Popper's point is a logical criterion applied in methodological naturalism. It is a tenet of realism that things exist or they don't, and what Popper is claiming is that claims about physical things, scientific claims must admit that they can only be true if they also might be false. Furthermore, often, we cannot often tell if something is always true, but it is often much simpler to show they are false. This, of course, is an outgrowth of induction, in which we make claims that appear to be true, but cannot be proven with deductive certainty. An example will help.
Let's claim that we have blurgles, and blurgles are some sort of machine. For a blurgle to be machine, it has to be a physical thing which produces an effect in the physical world. What Popper is claiming is that blurgles are only scientific entities if we can show blurgles produce an effect, and we apply truth-conditional semantics to that claim. In other words, "blurgles blurgify" is either true or false. Whether a blurgle blurgifies is empirical evidence. We use a blurgle and it works or it doesn't. If it doesn't, then the claim "blurgles blurgify" is false.
What is important to note is this is a LOGICAL criterion. It simply says, that science makes claims that must able to be false. If we unwrap, plug in, and press a button, and the blurgle fails, it is false that this particular blurgle blurgifies. We probably can't test all blurgles constantly and indefinitely, because that's not practical. But we can show that maybe one blurge doesn't work. Hence, the blurgle has a place in the scientific ontology.
But what happens if we have a competitor who claims to produce the perfect machine called the flurgle, but unlike the blurgle, the flurgle never fails? That would be an extraordinary claim. As scientists, we say, give us some of your flurgles, so we can see, but instead, you simply claim that flurgles are invisible, and cannot be seen by us. Well, we scientists say, then show us where your flurgles are made, and you claim, well the factory is hidden and no one knows where it is. Well, we ask, explain to us how your flurgle works, and you explain that it just does, because your flurgle manual says it does. Suddenly, we can see that blurgles and flurgles are two very different sorts of ontological primitives. Popper's claim is that since we cannot use logic to tell whether or not your claims are true or false, because the competitor insists we must take it on faith that it is always true, then we can make the counter claim that whatever a flurgle is, it is not a scientific and therefore physical thing. Perhaps its a religious artifact or magical totem, but it is not a physical machine because we cannot apply a realist's logical criterion rooted in truth-conditional semantics to it. If we cannot establish your claims might be false, then your claim does not jive with how our physical world works. Your flurgle is welcome to claim to be a supernatural machine, but it is not one that fits into naturalism, because all physical things admit to false claims.
There's nothing self-refuting about using that philosophical razor for determining whether something admits itself to the physical and naturalist framework and physically exists. It might be that the flurgle is an alien device, and it is indeed invisible, and that it is manufactured on an alien space station, and that given AI and advanced material science it never fails, but until we can inspect it and see if the claims you make about it are true and false, then we have to presume it doesn't exist and isn't scientific. Blurgles are scientifically real and flurgles are not. This is how scientific realism functions.
In this way, empirical evidence and the truth-conditions of logic are entwined. In no way does the failure of a flurgle to be subject to potentially false claims about physical observations mean that 'flurgle' is meaningless. In fact, the question about the flurgle isn't whether it means something, it clearly does. The question is whether the flurgle is real or fictional. A blurgle is real, clearly, but the flurgle appears to be fictional. It appears to be a reference with sense without a referent. Science, in this sense, cannot rule out furgles without repeating the mistake it made of ruling out black swans.
You ask:

Is the proposition "A statement is only meaningful if it can be falsified" itself falsifiable?

Here you commit a category mistake in your reasoning. Popper's criterion, is indeed a logic criterion, but it is about claims about empirical evidence, and the claim Popper makes is itself not a physical entity subject to physical observation. Popper's falsification is not just about any true or false claim, it is about true or false claims ABOUT the physical and natural world. Thus, you are mixing apples and oranges. Popper's claim cannot be the subject of empirical falsification because it is a belief, and beliefs are not  physical and therefore empirical entities.
